# Android : Theme.xml and Styles.xml?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-theme

In the newer version of Android Studio, I cant see `styles.xml`, but in the values directory, there are two new **XML**, `theme.xml` and `theme.xml(night)`.

Does it actually replace the work of `styles.xml` *OR* If different what is the difference between them??

Comment: Apart from that extra night mode now, it's the same thing, only named more appropriately. It has never mattered what the `values` files are named, actually. They all get processed. The ability to have separate and named files is just for the programmer's own organization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using XML attributes in `res\values` doesn't actually depend on the file name, you can define any of which like a `<string>` in another file like style.xml.

Even you can change the name of the `style.xml` to something that you'd like to.

In recent Android studio versions `styles.xml` is replaced by `themes.xml`, but the latter provides a night version for dark mode.

Comment: the awnser that i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

styles is a collection of attributes which define how a certain ui looks like **ex: editText or textView** a theme meanwhile decides how your whole app looks(a single theme can have multiple styles depends on your design), the difference between both themes day and night is to make your app adapt to day mode and night mode. Because now in android OS you can force dark mode.

As a developer you need to have your app prepared for this.

How to use this

give different colors to both your themes labelled in items(below is from a theme file)

```
  <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="Theme.<Your app name>" <---- this is autogenrated this wil be the id to be used
   parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
     </style>
     </resources>
```

To use in textview or button or layout file simpley just:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_StackOverflow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Theme.<Your app name>" /> <---insert your style name inside the theme.
```

Now when user force switch on dark mode in developer mode in their phone , your app will immediately adapt to it and change colors of its UI.

More info can be found here - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes